# Can I reuse the packages install on host OS in LXC guest OS?

Tags: linux, virtualization, lxc

I found that [LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/) is really light weight environment, which I would like to use. However, figured I have to reinstall every package that I want to use in guest environment.

I am wondering if I can reuse the packages installed on the Host OS inside my guest OS, because my Host and guest environment are exactly same, and I don't want to duplicate all those packages.

Googling for such topic did not reveal much information.

Comment: You can use a bind mount to share `/usr` of the host with the container, but this is off-topic on Stackoverflow. Questions on Linux usage get better answers here: http://unix.stackexchange.com